# Magento 2 - How to get data from customerRepository API?

Tags: magento2, customer, api

I can get **customer data using API repository**:

```
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
```

How do I get **the attribute data of the `$customer` object**?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We can get directly for some default attributes(take a look the API Data Customer interface: `vendor/magento/module-customer/Api/Data/CustomerInterface.php`) :

```
$customer->getEmail();
```

For custom attributes, we can get by `getCustomAttribute('your_attribute_code')`

```
$customer->getCustomAttribute('your_attribute_code')->getValue();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can find customer attribute data using below one,

```
$customerId = 1;
$customer = $this->customerRepository->getById($customerId);
```

Basic element like,

```
$customer->getEmail();
$customer->getId();
$storeId = $customer->getStoreId();
$groupId = $customer->getGroupId();
```

You can find default billing and shipping address like below one,
Using shipping and billing address you can find shipping and billing related info,

```
if ($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()) {
    $defaultBillingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getData();
    print_r($defaultBillingAddressId);
}
if ($customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()) {
    $defaultShippingAddressId = $customer->getDefaultShippingAddress()->getData();
    print_r($defaultShippingAddressId);
}
```